# I need to set as foreign key which refers to one of the composite primary key in other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

I have 3 tables with composite primary keys, I need to set as foreign key which refers to one of the primary key in other table.

ie,

- **table 1**: merchant(mId,mName,addid,..) pk(mId ,addId) .
- **table 2**: address(addId,name..) pk(addId)
- **table 3**: store(storeId,addId,mId,storename,..) pk(storeId,addId,mId)

`mId` in table store is a foreign key to primary key `mId` of merchants table,
`addId` in tbl store is foreign key to primary key in table Address.

How is this relationship set in sql server management studio express using gui?

Comment: The addId in store table, does it refer to the merchant's addId?

Comment: yes addId in store table refers to addId of Address and addId of merchant is fk to pk addId of Adreess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constraints could work like this, i.e. in a cascading style:

```
alter table store add constraint FK_store_merchant foreign key (mId, addId) references merchant (mId,addId)
alter table merchant add constraint FK_merchant_address foreign key (addId) references address (addId)
```

Not sure how you do this in the GUI, but just run this from a query window.

Comment: but addId of store is fk to addId in Address not addId in merchant

Comment: At the end of the day it won't matter. Basically, the combination of (mId, addId) needs to be valid, which in turn relies on (addId) being valid. So, the constraints enforce the relationships correctly. You may need to change, i.e drop, some of your existing constraints.

Comment: the below is my forkey requirement:CONSTRAINT `fk_Merchants_Address1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`addId` )  
REFERENCES `dotm`.`Address` (`addId` )

CONSTRAINT `fk_Stores_Merchants`
    FOREIGN KEY (`mId` )
 
   REFERENCES `dotm`.`Merchants` (`mId` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
   
CONSTRAINT `fk_Stores_Address1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`addId` )
  
  REFERENCES `dotm`.`Address` (`addId` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION

Comment: whwn i set the relation like u gave i am getting error coloumns in merchant do not match existing primary key or unquie constraint.

Comment: Can you post the exact error, and what you are trying to run? In your post, you said that merchant has a primary key of (mId, addId). If this is the case, you shouldn't get an error. Can you confirm the primary keys of the tables?

Comment: i had tried to add (addId, mid) instead of(mId,addId) thanks a lot it worked!!!!!:):) u saved my day

Comment: I have one more doubt:table 1: merchant(mId,mName,addid,..) pk(mId ,addId) .
table 2: deals(dealId,dealName,mId,dealImage,..) pk(dealId,mId) I need to add a forgein key: mId of deals which refers to pk mId of merchants

Comment: OK, this is where your current table structure is going to mess you up. The way you have things right now, deals would need to have an addId in order for you to create that foreign key. Are addresses always related to merchants, or do you store addresses for other entities?